# How can I remove a "log lighter" pipe from my fireplace?

Tags: pipe, fireplace

My fireplace has a log lighter:

[image]

What is the easy way to remove it?  Can I use WD-40 to loosen the connector?

Answer (score 1):

You will need two wrenches, one to hold the pipe coming out of the brick to prevent it from turning, and the other to unscrew the log-lighter "air mixing" fitting (the fitting has an adjustable flap that controls the amount of air pulled into the lighter pipe to allow for optimal flame). WD-40 or any other penetrating oil might help, and I would use pipe wrenches as it will probably be stubborn. If you slop a mess of oil around in there you should wipe up the excess before using an ignition source, just in case.

Comment: Before doing anything, make sure the gas supply for the lighter is disconnected and safely capped at a location well away from the fireplace.

Comment: @keshlam, this setup is normally/likely controlled by a 'log lighter" type thru wall shut-off valve which uses a key. No easy way to effect positive isolation besides closing the valve (short of turning off at the meter, which requires the whole pilot re-light exercise for other gas appliances). Should be fine with the valve off, there isn't raw unlit gas spewing from the pipe at the time of the photo, one would presume.

Comment: @jimmy I have a similar situation but it looks like my log lighter is painted over or something https://imgur.com/a/x2AQouD (that little spill is WD40). I’m starting to wonder that it’s not removable. I’m using two vise grep wrenches: one holding the pipe past that connector/fitting on the right, and one on the left of the fitting. Is it just stubborn and I have to try harder?

Comment: @Alaa Ali, definitely a pipe stubbing out of wall, then pipe coupling, then log-lighter pipe. You will need big pipe wrenches (as opposed to vice grip pliers).

Comment: Thanks @jimmy, I got the pipe off using a 10” pipe wrench!